Simulating realized variance
I have a question regarding possible ways to simulate realized variance (the sum of squared intraday returns) for testing different realized variance forecasting models.
I'm aware of several approaches to model stock prices, such as Geometric Brownian Motion and the Merton model. Recently, I was told that a simpler and more direct approach to simulate realized variance could involve using a HAR/AR model (for linear dependencies) something like this:
$$ RV_{t+1} = \phi_{1} RV_{t} + \phi_{2} RV_{t-1}+ ... + \phi_n RV_{t-n} + \epsilon_{t}$$ with $\epsilon$ following some distribution.
Additionally, I was told that an exponential model could be used for simulating non-linear dependencies. The goal of this simulation study is to evaluate how different realized variance forecasting models perform under both linear and non-linear dependency assumptions. However, I’ve struggled to find much literature explaining this specific approach to simulating realized variance.
This is why I wanted to ask:

How would you approach simulating realized variance for a simulation study
What kind of exponential model would be most appropriate for capturing non-linear dependencies in realized variance?
Can you recommend any literature that explores these or similar approaches?

Thanks a lot in advance!

In a simulation study, you get to decide what data generating process (DGP) to use. I would choose a DGP that I believe would best mimic the actual data that the models are going to be applied on.

Thanks a lot! The models will be applied to stock data (AAPL, MSFT etc...) this is why I am unsure what DGP to use, especially since it seems that there is not a lot of literature using these direct models for realized variance simulation (AR model and/or exponential model and not GBM) (at least that I can find).

Cross-posted on Cross Validated here. Rodion, the practice of posting the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites is frowned upon. On the other hand, it may be fine to do it with a week's delay if you get no good answers on your first attempt.

Alright, understand! Thanks for the info.

What Richard is right: find the DGP that best mimic actual data. One example of a "realistic" DGP for simulation studies regarding realized measures/models, is the 2-factor stochastic volatility model described in Appendix A of Bollerslev, Patton et al. (2016). This model is able to model the intraday volatility pattern as a diurnal U-shape through the $\sigma_{ut}$ function.  The simulation procedure is also described in Huang and Tauchen (2005) along with alternative DGPs.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
